# Why do the protected fields of type String not get Autowired, while other beans do

Tags: spring

I am trying to set value of `protected` `String` field in a annotation configured bean using `property-override` mechanism. It throws following exception unless I add a setter for the field in the bean.

```
 org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'cookie' of bean class [com.test.TestBean]: Bean property 'cookie' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

To compare I also have another `protected` field which is of type of another class. Bean of the other class is defined in XML. This field gets properly autowired.

Here's the first bean

```
@Component("testBean")
public class TestBean {

protected @Autowired(required=false) String cookie;
protected @Autowired InnerBean innerBean;

public String getCookie() {
    return cookie;
}

public void setCookie(String cookie) {
    this.cookie = cookie;
}

public InnerBean getInnerBean() {
    return innerBean;
}
}
```

Here's `InnerBean`

```
public class InnerBean {

private String value;

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}   
}
```

Spring configuration file - only interesting bits

```
<context:property-override location="beans.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"></context:component-scan>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<bean id="innerBean" class="com.test.InnerBean">
    <property name="value">
        <value>Inner bean</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

beans.properties

```
testBean.cookie=Hello Injected World
```

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test.xml");
    TestBean bean = context.getBean(TestBean.class);
    System.out.println("Cookie : " + bean.getCookie());
    System.out.println("Inner bean value : " + bean.getInnerBean().getValue());
}
```

Output

```
Cookie : Hello Injected World
Inner bean value : Inner bean
```

If I just comment out the setter for `cookie` in `TestBean`, I get the mentioned `NotWritablePropertyException` exception. Is there a difference between autowiring a bean and autowiring a property?

Answer (score 1):

`@Autowired` should only be used when you want to wire up a Spring bean to another bean.

Properties are set by `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` which is a different process to autowiring, and doesn't use the `@Autowired` annotation. That `@Autowired` annotation on the `cookie` property is unnecessary and probably confusing Spring's bean factory. I expect that simply removing the annotation should fix the problem for you, ie:

```
protected String cookie;
protected @Autowired InnerBean innerBean;
```

Spring is capable of setting properties even if they are private or protected.

Comment: Removing Autowired does not solve the problem. I see same behaviour as previous. I guess the `PropertyOverrideConfigurer` mechanism does not set protected properties.

Comment: @Lalit Mishra Read up on the different between setter based injection and autowiring. Setter-based injection needs a setter, autowiring does not.

Comment: @gresdiplitude It was not clear that `ProperyOverrideConfigurer` uses setter based mechanism. In fact the `TestBean` in my real issue is from a library (gwtp) that I am using. It defines the field with `@Autowired` but has not defined a setter.

Comment: I was able to work around by defining a bean of type `String`, but I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: Maybe you'd find it easier to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`? It allows you to configure fields like this: `@Value("${my.cookie}") protected String cookie;`. It's essentially the same but in reverse: instead of naming your properties after beans, you can choose any property name and specify the property name in your bean. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer for documentation.